# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'closest'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('.sign_in').closest('#page_canvas').css('marginTop','54px');
```

This line keeps throwing the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'closest'
```

Other jQuery functions are working fine, such as prependTo, remove, insertBefore. Not sure why the 'closest' function is not working. I spent the entire day researching, but found nothing specific. Any clues would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: What other libraries are you loading? I suspect some kind of conflict.

Comment: what version of jquery do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since other jQuery functions are working fine one of 3 things may be happening:**

1. You are using a jQuery version < 1.3
2. Another Javascript library is "stealing" `$` sign and thus making some conflict
3. At some point you are overriding `$` variable (try `jQuery` variable instead)